# gridview edit cell vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, webforms

I'm trying to get the cell value of an edited cell in a gridview. Can someone help me with my syntax?  This code works for the first line in a gridview:

```
Dim Q As Integer = e.NewValues(e.RowIndex)
```

but I receive and error if I update line 2... and my variable is " ":

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

This prints the correct row currently being edited:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(e.RowIndex)
```

I've even tried to get the cell value directly:

```
Dim Qoh As Integer = CInt(gvInventory.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text)
```

With an error:

```
Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

Comment: That's because it's empty... Your trying to convert nothing... Set a breakpoint and see what you get for your variable... Use CType to cast as an integer too

Comment: it shouldn't be empty.  it has a value.

Comment: Change .Text to .value in your variable

Comment: 'Value' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell'.

Comment: Is this for asp.net because in .net .value is correct for a gridview?

Comment: i'm using visual web developer express 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for my problem:

```
Dim Qoh As Integer = CInt(e.NewValues(0))
```

I assume it is because that is the only editable cell in the grid.

Comment: Only cell editable in the grid? I am confused unless you has set this for some reason or another. But I am glad you have your issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim Qoh As Integer = CType(gvInventory.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Text, Integer)
```

Try this one...

Comment: I did this and it still errors: Dim Qoh As Integer = CType(gvInventory.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text, Integer)      Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: I'm doing this in the RowUpdating event.  it seems it's not grabbing the updated value or even the old value in the cell.